# derivative of an integral with respect to matrix element

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, trace

I need to compute the following derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial V_{mn}} \int \prod_j d\phi_j \, \mathrm{Tr}
\left(\ln(i \phi + \beta J V)\right)
$$
where $\phi \equiv \phi_i \delta_{ij}$ is a diagonal matrix and $V$ is a matrix with elements $V_{mn}$ that are independent of $\phi_j$ (note the $i$ inside the natural log is the imaginary unit).

### My attempt

1) I understand the $V_{mn}$ and $\phi_j$ are independent, so the derivative can be carried into the integral.

2) I'm less sure about whether I can carry the derivative into the trace -- but I assume so because of linearity.

Then I would think the answer would be (with chain rule):

$$
\int \prod_j d\phi_j \, \beta J (i\phi + \beta J V)^{-1}_{mn}
$$

Is my reasoning/answer correct? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Replace the expression $\,\beta J(i\phi+\beta JV)^{-1}\,$ by $\,\,\beta J^T(i\phi+\beta JV)^{-T}.$

Comment: @greg 1) What does $-T$ as an exponent mean? inverse + transpose? 2) $J$ is a number, not a matrix. 3) why and how does the transpose come into play?